# Debug with Visual Studio 2015 on Android stop working

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, android-debug, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 RC to build and debug Android Apps on my Samsung Galaxy S5. Today I updated from android 4.3 to 5.0 and debugging stopped working. Here is the message I am getting:

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: I placed text and image in the correct order. Fixed some sentences.

Comment: Sir, trying doing what the error info says and see if it helps,after all that's the error log

Comment: How do you build Android apps on VS? Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this use Kies to flash the device and put 5.0 directly on it.

This was a bug in the Android updater, Google has since fixed but Samsung has been slow to get the fix into their versions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually after a software update it is best(recommended) that you do a factory reset of the phone. Also, make all android sdk updates available/android studio. But i'm think that after a factory reset it will be ok.